# Title page for report to exactly emulate \maketitle of article class

Tags: titles, article, report

I am currently writing a thesis using the "report" document class, but I need to be able to reproduce the effect that `\maketitle` has in the "article" class. This is because I submitted a title page to my institution that needs to be exactly the same in the final thesis, but the submitted title page used the "article" document class. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us some TeX code?

Comment: @Mensch What kind of code would be appropriate here? I haven't really messed at all with the \maketitle command

Comment: @Exitpath The best would be a sample compilable document using `article` class that shows how you produced the title page you submitted. Then people can help you adapt it to `report` class.

Comment: By default `article` uses option `notitlepage`, but `report` uses `titlepage`. So maybe you should add option `notitlepage` to `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 1):

If the title page needs to be exactly the same, one approach might be to use pdfpages and `\includepdf` the title page that you already gave them.

Answer (score 0):

Article class has two `\maketitle` definitions.  One creates a titlepage:

```
  \newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  }
```

The other uses:

```
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
    \begingroup
      \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
      \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
      \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
              \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
      \if@twocolumn
        \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
          \@maketitle
        \else
          \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
        \fi
      \else
      \newpage
        \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
        \@maketitle
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
    \endgroup
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
    \global\let\thanks\relax
    \global\let\maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@thanks\@empty
    \global\let\@author\@empty
    \global\let\@date\@empty
    \global\let\@title\@empty
    \global\let\title\relax
    \global\let\author\relax
    \global\let\date\relax
    \global\let\and\relax
  }
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
```